# Fix "array unique elements" script

Tags: arrays, bash, duplicates

There are a lot of similar threads for "unique elements in array", however following the ideas doesn't seem to work. Can you please check what's wrong with this simple one :

```
#!/bin/bash
lim=4
for a in `seq -s' ' 2 $lim`; do
  for b in `seq -s' ' 2 $lim`; do
  array=$(awk "BEGIN{print $a ** $b}")
  uniq=($( echo "${array[@]}" | sort -u ));echo "${uniq[@]}"
  done
done
```

It does print the a^b powers, but somehow fails to find the unique ones. Where am I  wrong ?

Sample output :
4
8
16
9
27
81
16
64
256

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the problem you are seeing is multi-faceted.

First, through each iteration of a*b you are assigning only a single value to the array, so that at any point in time your array contains only a single element.

Second, right after assigning the value to your array you are trying to sort for unique elements. It only has a single element so you get an echo back of a properly unique sorted single element array. Even if you were properly building your array you would still be unnecessarily sorting it after every single time you add an element to it. You only need to sort for unique once, after you fill your array.

Instead, fill your array inside your loop (properly) then outside of the loop, sort for unique:

```
#!/bin/bash
lim=4

#load the array
for a in `seq -s' ' 2 $lim`; do
        for b in `seq -s' ' 2 $lim`; do
                # properly add a new element to the array
                array=("${array[@]}" "$(awk "BEGIN{print $a ** $b}")")
        done
done

# echo original array
echo ${array[@]}

#find unique elements
uniqueArray=$(echo ${array[@]} | tr ' ' '\n' | sort -nu)

#echo unique array
echo ${uniqueArray[@]}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, as you said, the problem was not where I was looking at. It seems I need to re-read "the beginners' Bash" book again :)

Comment: To be honest, I didn't know that one off the top of my head. But I've worked with enough arrays in the past to feel like something wasn't quite right in the double for loops.